# jQuery - Setting number input value as float in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, floating-point

I have a function bound to the blur event for a specific class (attached to number type inputs) that is intended to force two decimal places. The following function works in Chrome, but does not work in Firefox.

Code:

```js
/**
 * Force 2 decimal places for specified inputs
 *
 */
$(document).on('blur', '.to-dec', function() {

  // get value
  var value = $(this).val();

  // no value
  if (!value) return;

  // cast to 2 decimal places
  value = parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);

  // update value
  $(this).val(value);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="to-dec" min="0" step="0.01" required>
```

If I output `value` before it is set, I get the expected value (ie. 3.00 for an input value of 3).

Anyone know why Firefox would be preventing this value to be set? I've already tried to use `parseFloat()` when setting the value with `val()`.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like Firefox automatically removes insignificant digits in `type=number`

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, I just found this bug report from 3 years ago: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1003896

Since this issue won't affect my functionality, I think I'll just let it fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An wasy way to make it work in FireFox will be to make the input type "text" and still maintain a type number behaviour with slight modifications to your code, Such as to clear the input if the value is NaN.

```js
$(document).on('blur', '.to-dec', function() {
  // get value
  var value = $(this).val();
  if (isNaN(value)) {
    $(this).val('');
  } else if (!value) {
    // no value
    return;
  } else {
    // cast to 2 decimal places
    value = parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
    // update value
    $(this).val(value);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="to-dec" min="0" step="0.01">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I forgot to included the 'required' attribute in my code example. I am verifying the validity of each field on my page whenever fields change to determine whether the user can move on to the next step in the form. I would like to keep the 'number' input type so that the red 'required' border still displays when an invalid value is entered, such as a negative number. However, I could just handle these restrictions in this function too.